# Problema con certificado SSL Charles en emulador

Tags: android

A ver si me podéis echar una mano. Estoy teniendo problemas con Charles a la hora de instalar el certificado SSL para poder esnifear las llamadas que hace mi aplicación. Por más que instalo el certificado, en las llamadas me dice que no está instalado, ¿donde debería instalarlo? No se si tengo que seguir algun paso en especial que me he saltado, y tampoco se muy bien si debo configurar el proxy en los ajustes del emulador o dentro del propio emulador.

Los pasos que he seguido para instalar el proxy son los básicos, no he hecho nada especial. Después lo que yo tenía entendido que tenía que tocar es lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí como se puede ver he añadido en Include a todos. En Proxy Settings tengo estas opciones marcadas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora me surge una duda, ¿en el proxy tengo cual de las dos IP tengo que coger? He pillado la segunda pero no estoy seguro si es así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por último en Android Studio me he ido, con el emulador abierto a Settings del propio emulador y en el apartado de proxy he añadido la IP y el puerto 8888, parece que lo pilla bien pero las llamadas salen como "unknow", he ido a instalar el certificado en el movil desde la url http://chls.pro/ssl como indica en Charles, lo descargo e instalo, pero en el emulador me aparece todo el rato un mensaje diciendo que compruebe si el certificado es de confianza, le doy, le digo que si, pero el mensaje sigue ahí, y después en Charles el mensaje que me muestra en las llamadas es *"SSL handshake with client failed: An unknown issue occurred processing the certificate (certificate_unknown)"*

Comment: Hola! Una consulta, este error te pasa en alguna version de Android específica? Por ejemplo Android 5? Yo tuve un problema similar :D

Comment: Pues he probado tanto en Android 6, 9 y 10 y nada...

Comment: Oka. Ya intentaste cargar el certificado mediante código? Es decir tal vez el certificado que utilizas no este dentro de los certificados que acepta el device de Android y por eso no te lo reconoce.

Comment: ¿Como se hace mediante código?

Answer (score 1):

Podrias intentar instalarlo por código, en muchas ocasiones el certificado que utilizamos por el lado de backend no son reconocidos por los devices android. En un caso particular me pasó que para devices con Android 5, no reconocía el certificado, pero para versiones superiores si lo reconocía. A lo mejor, en tu casa pasa para todos. Entonces para resolver esto, android nos provee de algunas soluciones.

- La primera es aceptar todos los certificados que exista ( esta no es la mejor solución por razones de seguridad, no es bueno aceptar fuentes extrañas)
- Una segunda solución es instalar el certificado que tienes en tu backend en tu aplicación, es decir cada vez que haces una llamada a tu backend, como ya tienes el certificado instalado no tendrás problemas porque internamente lo tiene instalado. Considero que es la manera más seguro y la que android recomienda. Aceptar fuente de datos solo que nosotros confiemos. Es decir si algún otro enpodint por algún motivo intenta conectarse con nuestra app, no podrá porque no reconocerá el certificado de ese endpoint. Como no todo es 100% puede que exista maneras de evadir esta seguridad, pero es más complicado.

Entonces para instalar tu certificado podrías hacer lo siguiente:

Dentro de tu carpeta `assets` tienes que agregar tu certificado, generalmente tiene la extension `.crt` por ejemplo  -> `certificado.ctr`.

Luego que lo tenemos en nuestra carpeta `assets`, procederemos a llamarlo mediante código e instalarlo.

```
// Cargamos nuestro certificado desde la ubicación mencionada, puedes ubicarlo en algún otro lado, si deseas. Pero creo que la mejor ubicación es en assets
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("certificado.ctr"));
Certificate ca;
try {
    ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
    System.out.println("ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
} finally {
    caInput.close();
}

// Creamos un keyStore con nuestro certificado
String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
keyStore.load(null, null);
keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

// Creamos un Trust Manager que maneja el keyStore con el certificado previamente cargado
String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
tmf.init(keyStore);

// Creamos la conexión
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

// En este ejemplo cuando llamamos a un endpoint [https://certs.cac.washington.edu/CAtest/], ahora ya no tendremos el error porque, al llamar al endpoint podemos observar que le adjuntamos el certificado que hemos creado previamente 
URL url = new URL("https://certs.cac.washington.edu/CAtest/");
HttpsURLConnection urlConnection =
    (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
copyInputStreamToOutputStream(in, System.out);
```

Finalmente este ejemplo es del mismo android, Dejare las referencias para más detalle. Se puede integrar con alguna librerías que estes utilizando como retrofit, y es de manera similar. cargar el certificado, asignarle un keyStore para procesarlo y luego cargarlo en tus llamadas a los endpoints.

Espero Te ayude :)

Referencias  : https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl